# Convert Time string into hours using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following format of data in Excel.

```
1 hour
5 hours
30 mins
2 hours 30 mins
1 hour 45 mins
```

I would like to convert this to the following

```
1
5
0.5
2.5
1.75
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: did you try anything? can you post your attempted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have hours and minutes, a few substitutions should do the trick:

```
=(IF(ISERROR(FIND("hour",A1)),"00:","")&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"s","")," hour", ":00"),":00 ",":")," min",""))*24
```

Remove the extra `s` first, then substitute the `hour` by `:00`, then substitute `:00`  with nothing to 'stick' the hours and minutes together, finally remove the `min`.

If there is no `hour` in the text, prepend `00:` and multiply the whole thing by 24 to convert the time into hours.